# How to extract the value of last days from each year(1990-2011)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Question: Create a time series for every year with the sales volume listed for Apple (AAPL) on 31 December.

Screenshot of `volume.csv` data:

[image: Screenshot of volume.csv data]

Screenshot of AAPL data only:

[image: Screenshot of AAPL data only]

If the data does not contain a record for this date, then take the last known value that this known prior to that date.

My codes:

```
file = 'volume.csv'

apple = pd.read_csv(file)
apple_new = apple.drop(['AA', 'GE', 'IBM', 'JNJ', 'MSFT', 'PEP', 'SPX', 'XOM'], axis=1)

print(apple_new)
```

How to extract only "last days of the year" from each year(1990-2011)?

Comment: something to the effect of df.groupby('Year').tail(1) If you can pull the year from the Date and groupby, tail(1) gives the entry for that  year.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has picture graphics containing the question rather than searchable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have loaded the data into dataframe, create a column with only the year.

Assume your `Date` column is in date format. If not:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then create the year column:

```
df['year'] = df.Date.dt.year
```

Then extract all the records from df with drop_duplicates (keep=last). This will be the values you need.

```
dfX = df.drop_duplicates(['year'],keep='last')
```

This will give you the desired result (my data is from 1981 thru 2021):

```
            Date        AAPL
247   1981-12-31    0.098772
500   1982-12-31    0.133371
753   1983-12-30    0.108817
1006  1984-12-31    0.130022
1258  1985-12-31    0.098214
1511  1986-12-31    0.180804
1764  1987-12-31    0.375000
2017  1988-12-30    0.359375
2269  1989-12-29    0.314732
2522  1990-12-31    0.383929
2775  1991-12-31    0.503348
3029  1992-12-31    0.533482
3282  1993-12-31    0.261161
3534  1994-12-30    0.348214
3786  1995-12-29    0.284598
4040  1996-12-31    0.186384
4293  1997-12-31    0.117188
4545  1998-12-31    0.365513
4797  1999-12-31    0.917969
5049  2000-12-29    0.265625
5297  2001-12-31    0.391071
5549  2002-12-31    0.255893
5801  2003-12-31    0.381607
6053  2004-12-31    1.150000
6305  2005-12-30    2.567500
6556  2006-12-29    3.030000
6807  2007-12-31    7.074286
7060  2008-12-31    3.048214
7312  2009-12-31    7.526072
7564  2010-12-31   11.520000
7816  2011-12-30   14.464286
8066  2012-12-31   19.006071
8318  2013-12-31   20.036428
8570  2014-12-31   27.594999
8822  2015-12-31   26.315001
9074  2016-12-30   28.955000
9325  2017-12-29   42.307499
9576  2018-12-31   39.435001
9828  2019-12-31   73.412498
10081 2020-12-31  132.690002
10086 2021-01-08  132.050003
```